# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException web service error in java

Tags: java, web-services

I have create a simple web service in Java (using Eclipse IDE).

The code for my project is:

```java
package cris;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class ReqH {

  @WebMethod 
  public String test() {
    return "test from web service";
  }

  @WebMethod
  public String add(int a, int b) {
    int c = a + b;
    return " "+c;
  }
}
```

I have create a WSDL using Eclipse and copy paste this WSDL file in my client project and generate the client using this code:

```java
package cris;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class ClinetTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReqHProxy rs=new ReqHProxy();
    try {
      String r=rs.test();
      System.out.println("Result of calling test method"+r);
      String res = rs.add(5, 5);
      System.out.println(res);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

When I start the server and trying to run the client. I am getting exception

> INFO: Tried to invoke method public java.lang.String cris.ReqH.add(int,int) with arguments java.lang.Integer,null.  The arguments do not match the signature.
>   **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException**

Comment: Side note: `" "+c` ?? Why not `""+c` or better `Integer.toString(c)`? I'd guess you don't need that extract space and `""+c` would result in calling `Integer.toString(c)` anyways but you have the additional string concatenation that isn't needed at all.

Comment: no effect i have used both but no effect on the exception

Comment: Do you get the result from `rs.test()`? The exception's message is quite clear: there's a call that looks like `rs.add(x,null)` which can't work. Did you track down the line that issues this call? Are you sure you're running the correct version of your code (i.e. could it be that compilation failed and you're still running an old version)?

Comment: i have wriiten the jsp code on the server and test <%@page import="cris.ReqH" %>
<%

ReqH rq=new ReqH();
String r=rq.add(5,5);
out.println(r);
out.println("hello");
%>   and get the result but in client not getting

Comment: Did you write `ReqHProxy`? If so, what does it look like? Did you debug your client?

Comment: yes sir @Thomas i am definitely sure for code running

Comment: yes sir i have debug  String res = rs.add(5, 5); on the above line it throws me out from the try block

Comment: So what does `ReqHProxy` look like?

Comment: hir my request proxy is look like https://github.com/anildsvv14/Php-multiple-image-upload/blob/master/ReqHProxy.java    plz help me out

Comment: Hmm, that looks correct so it seems to either be a problem with the call itself or some other place is actually calling the wrong parameters. Can you provide the stacktrace of the exception (note: edit your question and add it as a code block)? Are you able to somehow get hold of the actual network traffic to see what's sent to the webservice?

Comment: yes sir here is stracetrace https://github.com/anildsvv14/Php-multiple-image-upload/blob/master/exception

Comment: You didn't fully read my comment,especially the note, did you? Besides that your stacktrace says line 10 but if I count lines in your post the call is at line 11, so there must be a difference. Try creating two local variables `a` and `b`, print them to command line before the call and then call `rs.add(a,b)`.

Comment: i have try to print and same error occurred https://github.com/anildsvv14/Php-multiple-image-upload/blob/master/exception sir really i am not understanding how this exception occurred

Comment: Well in that case I don't know either. If you posted your actual code and did everything I suggested then it should work from my pov. If it doesn't then either there's a bug in axis or there's some other problem. You could still dive into the call with a debugger (and source code for axis should be available to help with that) and see what's actually sent to the webservice or where the data gets changed.

Comment: ok sir thanks for your help